# How to install Asterisk with SRTP support?

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, sip, ubuntu-13.04

I'm rather new to Asterisk, and I need my server to support WebRTC. As far as I know, Asterisk version in Asterisk Now is compiled without SRTP support, which is necessary for WebRTC.

So, I try to compile Asterisk 11.5.0 with SRTP on my Ubuntu server 13.04. I execute ./configure command with --with-srtp option. Here is this command:

```
./configure --with-crypto --with-ssl --with-srtp
```

But I get a warning:

```
checking for the ability of -lsrtp to be linked in a shared object... no
configure: WARNING: ***
configure: WARNING: *** libsrtp could not be linked as a shared object.
configure: WARNING: *** Try compiling libsrtp manually. Configure libsrtp
configure: WARNING: *** with ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr
configure: WARNING: *** replacing /usr with the prefix of your choice.
configure: WARNING: *** After re-installing libsrtp
configure: WARNING: *** configure script.
configure: WARNING: ***
configure: WARNING: *** If you do not need SRTP support re-run configure
configure: WARNING: *** with the --without-srtp option.
```

My libsrtp (v 1.4.4) is already compiled with the options, mentioned above! I've also tried to set location of libsrtp, while configuring Asterisk:

```
./configure --with-crypto --with-ssl --with-srtp=/usr/include/srtp
```

but this changes nothing.

Can you help me with WebRTC support in Asterisk?

UPD: I think, there is a problem in SRTP library, because it does not pass runtest properly: Error 254.
They write, changing "RTPW=rtpw" to "RTPW=./rtpw" in rtpw_test.sh will fix this error, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the development headers? You should be able to get 1.4.4 in the repositories and not have to compile from source. That is what I did although I am not on Ubuntu 13.04.

```
apt-cache search libsrtp
```

should hopefully yield either libsrtp-dev or libsrtp1-dev or something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

In SRTP Folder

```
make uninstall
make clean
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr/local/lib
make
make runtest
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Gentoo and emerging Asterisk with srtp flag solved my problem. Any solution for Ubuntu was not finded, regardless on 2 days of earnest search.